# How to iterate through a list containing search queries using a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, append, tweepy

I am trying to iterate through a list containing different search queries. Each element in the list 'search_query_list' differentiates on the name and Twitter username of a politician.

```
search_query_list = 
['(block me OR blocked me) -vote -$2000 -Senate -House -is:retweet lang:en (SenJonKyl OR Jon Kyl)', 
'(block me OR blocked me) -vote -$2000 -Senate -House -is:retweet lang:en (DougJones OR Doug Jones)', 
'(block me OR blocked me) -vote -$2000 -Senate -House -is:retweet lang:en (timkaine OR Tim Kaine)']
```

I am trying to iterate through each element in the list and extract tweets for each politician using a for loop. However, for some unknown reason, the code does not extract any tweets?

```
pol_tweets = [] # Empty list

def getTweets():
    client = getClient()
    for x in searh_query:
        tweets = client.search_all_tweets(query=x,
                                          tweet_fields=['created_at', 'author_id'],
                                          start_time='2017-01-01T00:00:00Z',
                                          max_results=30,
                                          expansions=['attachments.media_keys', 'author_id'],
                                          media_fields=['preview_image_url', 'url'],
                                          user_fields=['description'])

        return pol_tweets.append(tweets) # Append tweets to empty list

results = getTweets()
```

Output

```
print(results)
None
```

Comment: can you add the expected output, its bit confusing -  client = getClient(): and client.search_all_tweets()

Answer (score 0):

i dont exactly know what the other called functions do but you have a return statement for every result.

please try

```
def getTweets():
client = getClient()
pol_tweets = []
for x in search_query:
    tweets = client.search_all_tweets(query=x,
                                      tweet_fields=['created_at', 'author_id'],
                                      start_time='2017-01-01T00:00:00Z',
                                      max_results=30,
                                      expansions=['attachments.media_keys', 'author_id'],
                                      media_fields=['preview_image_url', 'url'],
                                      user_fields=['description'])

    pol_tweets.append(tweets) # Append tweets to empty list
return pol_tweets
```

print(getTweets())

As you can see i define the empty array in the function getTweets and append items to the list in your for loop.

after all iterations are done i return the finished array.
with dummy data this worked for me.

Comment: Hi Stefan. Thanks for your reply. When using your code I only extract tweets for the first politician in the search_query_list i.e. Jon Kyle. I have increased the max_result to 500 so it is not because I reach the limit of extracted tweets before it iterates to the next politician on the list.